# android - search word in chrome browser only

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app that takes keyword from user and it should search that word in Google Chrome browser only. How can I force it to open in Chrome only.

When I click Search button opera and Google App are only options to search with.Google Chrome is installed but its not showing in options.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.keyword);
            String content = text.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, content);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have tried to following line of code but exec gives an error may be its not for android

````
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]
  {
       "chromium-browser", "http://example.com/"shoes" }
  );
 ```
search is possible by opera and googleApp only but google chrome is not an option
````

Comment: Can `Chrome CustomTab` be useful to your problem? https://segunfamisa.com/posts/chrome-custom-tabs

Comment: Actually yes! You've shown me a direction. Thanks

Comment: So I just turn it into an answer. Feel free to accept for future uses.

Answer (score 0):

Android support library already includes APIs where you can open your URLs in a chrome browser. It's called **chrome custom tabs**.

1. Add Gradle dependency:

`implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:+'`

2. Usage:

```
// Use a CustomTabsIntent.Builder to configure CustomTabsIntent.
String url = "https://www.example.com/";
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

// set toolbar color and/or setting custom actions before invoking build()
// Once ready, call CustomTabsIntent.Builder.build() to create a CustomTabsIntent
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();

// and launch the desired Url with CustomTabsIntent.launchUrl()
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

More information on [chrome custom tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs).